# WSO2 API Manager - postgres issue on new install

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Trying to install API Manager 1.6, fresh install with postgresql. I've followed all of the directions, created the databases, but when it comes to the WSO2AM_DB, this isn't being created properly from either `wso2server.sh -Dsetup`, or using the postgres.sql script in the dbscripts\apimgt folder. The error I keep running into is:
 `ERROR:  relation "am_worflows_sequence" does not exist`. The WSO2_CARBON_DB gets populated without any problems.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. Thanks for reporting. There is an error in the postgresql.sql script. Please replace the AM_WORKFLOWS table definition as below and re run the script.

```
CREATE TABLE AM_WORKFLOWS(
    WF_ID INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('am_workflows_sequence'),
    WF_REFERENCE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    WF_TYPE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    WF_STATUS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    WF_CREATED_TIME TIMESTAMP,
    WF_UPDATED_TIME TIMESTAMP,
    WF_STATUS_DESC VARCHAR(1000),
    TENANT_ID INTEGER,
    TENANT_DOMAIN VARCHAR(255),
    WF_EXTERNAL_REFERENCE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (WF_ID),
    UNIQUE (WF_EXTERNAL_REFERENCE)
)
;
```

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2029